# How to access outer object in javascript objects

Tags: javascript

Assume code like. I want to access i and j in some function somefunc. How will this be achieved?

```
var myObj = function(){
Object.defineProperty(this, 'j'){
 get: function() { return 1;}
};
}

myObj.prototype =  Object.create(null);
myObj.prototype={
   constructor : myObj,
   i : 1,
   somefunc : function(){
       console.log(i + j);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `this.i` and `this.j`? If `somefunc()` doesn't get called in a different context (with `call()` or so) it should be the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

They can be accessed through this.i and this.j

```
var myObj = function(){
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'j'){
        get: function() { return 1;}
    };
}

myObj.prototype =  Object.create(null);
myObj.prototype={
   constructor : myObj,
   i : 1,
   somefunc : function(){
       console.log(this.i + this.j);
   }
}
```